# localeCompare() platform support

Tags: javascript, android, sorting, locale

I want to sort an array of French, German, Polish, Chinese etc. words in javascript.

Therefore I use the localeCompare() method as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

In this pen you can see the french example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWWYoy?editors=1111

Left side is the ordering it should be - right side the order the browser generates.

Same example with german letters: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezzPWa

```
function frsort(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}
```

I'm simply using localeCompare without locales or options arguments, since those are supported by very few browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

However developers.mozilla.org reads:

> Android - Basic support (Yes)

Even though on Android 4.0.4 using the Android browser sorting is done all wrong. Chrome on Android 4.0.4 sorts the right way.

[image]

Is there any mistake in my code, or any explanation why Stock Android browser is doing the sorting wrong?

Comment: MDN isn't perfect. It's also a wiki, so you can add notes for implementations where you've found issues.

Answer (score 0):

The stock Android browser is showing the correct behaviour if you are not specifying options. It's the options that are supposed to deal with accent-folding.

```
a.localeCompare( b, 'fr', { sensitivity: 'base' } );
```

If you need to support accent folding on older browsers you'll want to roll your own. https://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete